# Copy a structure inside a function in C/C++ with/without memcpy

Tags: c++

```
void func(struct a* para) 
{
  struct b *alpha;
  memcpy(&alpha, para, sizeof(para));
  new_func(&alpha); //because this requires struct of type b
}
```

Am i missing any kind of initializations here? I tried "struct b *alpha {}" also. Is there any other method to copy the structure inside a function? If not advisable, then can someone tell me how to use the memcpy method?

My device throws bus errors and I have observed this error before due to non initialization or some memory related issues.

EDIT:
struct a and struct b are the same
`struct a`
`{`

```
char alpha;
int beta;
```

`}`

Comment: Is `sizeof(b) >= sizeof(a)`?

Comment: The syntax suggests this is C, not C++.

Comment: @JHBonarius Yeah but my code is in C++. Shall I edit the question as C/C++?

Comment: @tadman it's the same

Comment: please give a [mcve]... what is `a`? what is `b`? If you're using pointer type aliasing (`reinterpret_cast`), you're not using C++ the intended way.

Comment: struct a and struct b are exactly the same structures. I have edited the question. What do you suggest instead of using reinterpret_cast? @JHBonarius

Comment: Why do you have require two different structs if they have the same layout? Why not one struct and two objects of that type?

Answer (score 3):

You're copying data over an uninitialized pointer, and the pointer itself is too small, so it just explodes. An easy fix:

```
b alpha; // struct prefix not necessary in C++

// Note sizeof(a) not sizeof(a*)
memcpy(&alpha, para, sizeof(a));

// Presuming this takes b* arg, not b** arg as your code implies
new_func(&alpha);
```

Note that if `new_func` retains that pointer it will be invalidated the instant `func` exits.

If all this is to just pass in something that's of one type but you want it to be another, just use [`static_cast`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_cast) and save yourself all this hassle:

```
new_func(static_cast<b*>(para));
```

Comment: Yes that was the purpose, reinterpret_cast worked instead of static

Comment: Even better, nice.